# Dilation of simple shapes

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I wanted to know if there is an easy way to dilate different shapes that I have. In the end I want to obtain the different areas' and perimeters' equations of the new dilated shape with respect to the given parameters and the scaling factor.

I have for example those two shapes here, anyone can guide me through this?

I was thinking about dilating  the rectangle first in which those shape resides in by a certain factor and then obtain the areas of the shape here based on the dilated rectangle, would that work?

Cheers

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion is correct. If you scale the parameters by some scaling factor, then the perimeter and area of the new figure will be easily obtained.
For example, in figure "$6$", if you scale each parameter by '$k$', then for the new perimeter, $P'$, we will have that $P'=kP$. Alternatively, for the new area, $A'$, we will have that $A'=k^2A$. This is easy to see if you write out the area formula for a trapezoid and factor out the scaling factor from the 'base' and 'height' terms of the formula. This is pretty much a general fact when scaling figures by a constant scaling factor.

If you have a more complicated figure, like figure "$7$", then I suggest breaking the figure up into rectangles and triangles (or some other figure that has an easily computed area, like a trapezoid) in order to find the area of the new scaled figure in terms of the parameters. Still relatively easy with some simple relations and trigonometry, but more computationally intensive than a simpler figure.

I have [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3757432/803927) closely related to this one if you want to check it out.

Hope this helped.